Como puedo poner un hipervinculo en una cadena de texto en java
Tengo la siguiente variable:
String mensaje = "Puedes validar la siguiente información completa %s"
String contentMessage = String.format(
mensaje,
//hipervinculo);
Básicamente, lo que debo hacer es que después de donde dice completa haya un aquí, que sea un hipervínculo, digamos a https://www.google.com.
Todo esto debe ser en texto plano, ya que el mensaje es para enviarlo como mensaje de texto a un celular.

Me suena a uno de esos mensajes de spam, pero, que has intentado en código?

Dado que el mensaje lo vas a enviar como texto plano y no directamente como un hipervículo usando <a href ...> o algún otro formato similar, no hay forma de ponerlo directamente como un link clicable, sin embargo, si puedes incluir el hipervínculo como una cadena de texto y, en casi todos los dispositivos, lo va a reconocer automáticamente como un link.
A nivel código lo puedes trabajar como cadenas de texto separadas de la siguiente forma:
String mensaje = "Aquí va el mensaje antes del hipervículo o lo que quieras mostrar";

// Adaptas tu link
String link = "https://www.google.com";

String contentMessage = String.format(mensaje, link);

Cuando lo manejes como un mensaje de texto que se enviará a un celular, este mismo le dará el formato necesario para reconocerlo como un link clicable, sin la necesidad de tu tener que modificarlo o hacer una adaptación adicional.
